# Finding A Function Yielding Harmonic Values Up To A Finite Number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

I've asked this question in differing ways, and arrived at this, as perhaps a better way to phrase it:

Is there a function for the following:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
1+\frac12 & 2 \\
1+\frac12+\frac13 & 3 \\
1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}$$

I'm told that this can't be done to infinity; so, is there a function that yields the correct numbers up to $$y=10$$, for instance.

Comment: What's the question?  There's no difficulty computing the partial sums by hand up to a low level like $10$...is that what you are asking?

Comment: Can you write such a sum for me? Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form calculation of $H(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$? You can find one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation

Comment: Would you be willing to simplify it down to something a bit more friendly looking? If you don't mind!

Thank you!

Comment: I mean...for such small sums you can do it by hand.  Or use a computer, as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BSum%5B1%2Fn%2C+%7Bn%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C10%7D%5D)

Comment: No, it was an example, I want something that can, in principle do it up to very high numbers!

Comment: @lulu, I'm going to be using this function as a component of another for a graph.

Comment: So, use one of the asymptotic formulas you can find in the linked wikipedia article.  As you'll have seen, exact computations for the Harmonic numbers are not pleasant.

Comment: I'd be fine with any level of difficulty, so long as it can be written out like a typical (algebra) function; I don't care how long it is, or what not. Can you link to such a thing?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your time!!

Comment: To be clear, the formulas in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation are unacceptable to you because they involve things  like integrals, and factorials, and so on, that are not "like a typical (algebra) function". Is that correct?

Comment: @LeeMosher, I personally would be fine with these things; though when I first saw the wiki formula, I thought it had more variables than it did. My concern is that these things likely can't be incorporated into the contexts in which I plan to use the function. I and pretty much everyone on here could simply lay out a list of arbitrary definitions and operations that would yield the desired result. But, this wouldn't be of any practical use.

Comment: Maybe I should have a closer look at the approximations; the issue is, as far as I've seen, they tend not to hit the lower numbers too well, which is what I want.